# Is it possible to navigate to a parent directory in the jupyter tree?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, path, jupyter-notebook

Normally, I launch jupyter from a new bash terminal:

```
~$ jupyter notebook
```

and then navigate *down* the tree to the files I want to work at.

I just did it from a terminal that was already running at a different path:

```
~/blah/blah/blah$ jupyter notebook
```

and realized that that directory becomes the *home* for jupyter. I wanted to work at a file located at, say `~/blah/thingy/luis.ipynb`, but couldn't find my way *up*.

**How do I navigate the directory tree *upwards* in jupyter notebook?**

Comment: I don't think this is possible at the moment

Comment: @cel Yes, it looks like that. Do you know why? I am just curious about it, it's not a bad issue or something (for me at least)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As explained in https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7751, it is not possible to navigate to the parent directory for security reasons:

> The kernel might not be python, nor on the same machine than the
>   server, nor do you need a running kernel to use server API(s).

If you want, you can ask for more information in the aforementioned GitHub issue.

Comment: It's also discussed here https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2032

Answer (score 0):

As [edwinksl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486919/edwinksl) pointed out it is not possible for security reasons. See https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2032.

But if you want to keep your luis.ipynb file in its original location and still be able to access it from Jupyter Notebook browser, you can create a symlink to it in your running Jupyter Notebook directory:

`ln -s ~/blah/thingy/luis.ipynb ~/blah/blah/blah/`

For more details on symlinks see https://www.howtogeek.com/297721/how-to-create-and-use-symbolic-links-aka-symlinks-on-a-mac/