# How to find parent directory in iPython

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm using iPython (Jupiter notebook) for visualizing my data. I planned storage my input data outside of the git repository liked that:

```
root/
|- git_repository/
|  |- research.ipynb
|- storage/
|  |- raw_data/
|  |  |- example.odx
...
```

I tried to import `example.odx` from all storages folder (raw_data, research_data...) to my code by this code below:

```
In  [1]: from os import listdir
         from os.path import isdir
         files = [file for file in listdir('../storage') if isdir(file)]
Out [1]: []
```

My output is `[]` mean I can not find my data. I tried some string path below however It still fails.

```
>>> from os import path
>>> path.join(path.dirname(__file__), '../')
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

```
'./../storage', '../../storage', '../', './../', './../storage/', './..', '..'
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282336/is-it-possible-to-navigate-to-a-parent-directory-in-the-jupyter-tree

Comment: Thank mr.@i_th for your suggested. I read it carefuly however this question mean how to change the home directory of the iPython server after started. I think that not point to my question.

Answer (score 1):

`.` represents the current directory and
`..` represents the previous to the current directory

You can simply access your example.odx

```
path = '../storage/raw_data/example.odx'
```

from your git directory and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank mr.@i_th and mr.@tbtihaj-tahir,

I found my problem's solution here:

[Python not recognising directories os.path.isdir()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761473/python-not-recognising-directories-os-path-isdir)

The iPython got a problem, I think. So I have to `os.path.join` the path which I invoke `listdir` on with the found file/directory, i.e.

```
for each in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, each)):
        ....
```

`[file for file in listdir('../storage') if isdir(file)]` work well on windows cmd but `[file for file in listdir('../storage') if isdir(join('../storage', file))]` on `jupyter notbook`